# Block archived event inside blockchain

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, events, randomness, timers

I want to write a gambling smart contract, that will be based on time (on block number in the ethereum blockchain).

**What is the best way to do some work when current network block will archive some number?** For example, I want to close the current round and send all awards to winners when current network block will archive 6320132 number?

Comment: "block will archive 6320132 number" <-- you can't guarantee that, miners might not  include your transaction at this block number if , for example, you use lower transaction fee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do it without relying on anything that triggers at that moment.

You use the `block.number` to decide if bets are allowed.

```
function isOpen() {
  return(block.number <= deadline);
}

function bet( ... {
  require(isOpen());
  ...
}
```

You determine a winner retroactively.

```
function didIWin( ... {
  if(!isOpen()) return false;
  return winner() == msg.sender;
}
```

The tricky part is creating a fair game. This might involve concealing moves from other players or trying to introduce randomness. Those are non-trivial challenges.

```
function winner() { ...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `block.number` will return the current block number.